# Outlook Search Function - Save/Hide Search Properties

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search

Previously in Outlook, if I clicked into the search field in e-mail, a search window would appear with several search properties I had previously selected.  When I clicked away from the search (i.e. to another folder/e-mail), the search window would minimise but when I clicked into the search field again, the same search window with the same properties would reappear.

Now however, the last search does not appear, I have to add each search property again and the search window stays open (taking up a good portion of the view) when I'm finished searching.  Then I have to click X on each search property to get rid of them.

If I want to search again I have to repeat the whole process, instead of the last search appearing/dropping down with the last set of criteria I used.

I haven't changed laptop or MS version so I'm not sure why this has changed, but would like to be able to click into the Search window and have the last search properties appear and then disappear when I click again.